# psql: error: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-15

After installing and opening the psql shell, it throws this error BEFORE even asking the password I had set during install:

```
psql: error: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

I enter the default user ("postgres") and it immediately throws the error before prompting me to enter the password as everyone else's shell.

Tried to look at the `pg_hba.conf` file and changing the METHOD from `scram-sha-256` (the one that was originally set) to `md5` and `password`, but no good.

I know I can just set it to `trust` but that doesn't seem right. Why is this happening? How can it be an installing mistake if it doesn't even wait for me to the enter the password?

Comment: What is "the psql shell"?  People who say that are usually on Windows and are talking about some kind of bat file which is wrapper, not the real `psql` binary.

Comment: If a password is supplied by .pgpass file or by PGPASSWORD environment, then psql (without -W option) will not prompt for a password, but will just use the one supplied.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to use PostgreSQL on Windows (my desktop at work). It comes with an app called SQL Shell (psql) and the pgAdmin 4 app. When I open the SQL Shell and try to connect, it throws the error. Also, I can't find the .pgpass file on %appdata% or anywhere else, even though i'm checking for hidden items on the Explorer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, check did you set up a password for the 'postgres' user.
Then try to change in the file */var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf*
all values 'ident' to 'scram-sha-256'
And then restart server: *sudo systemctl restart postgresql.service*

Answer (score 1):

Open terminal.

Log in to your postgres sql: `sudo -u postgres psql postgres`

You have to set up a new password for postgre so now
After you see the postgres prompt type in: `\password postgres`

Enter your new password, confirm it and reopen postgres again. This should work.

Comment: Your solution was helpful, this worked for me `sudo -u postgres psql postgres`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with `psql` shell on Windows. I solved it by running the `pg_env.bat` file in `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\16rc1\` before running `psql`.This file sets the environment variables for PostgreSQL, such as `PGUSER` and `PGDATA`. After running `pg_env.bat`, `psql` accepted my password and connected to the server successfully.

Comment: This file doesn't exist in my case